# selenium chromedriver browser not open after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my MVC web application, I'm using selenium C# web driver to read some data from HTML file. my application works properly when I execute my application through VS(HTML file opening through chrome and reading HTML properly). But after I publish and host application in IIS server HTML file not opening through the chrome browser. (browser not opening), here is my code.

```
public class CribController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Selenium\");

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("D:/Crib/toEdit_Foramted V2.html");
        string text = driver.Title;

        var table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("reportcontainerstyle-Ver2"));
        var rowsss = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

        //To get days arrears details
        var mainTable = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ConsumerCreditDetails_Version3"));
        var subTables = mainTable.FindElements(By.Id("bandstyle-Ver2"));

            var rows = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[.//td[normalize-space(.)='Credit Facility (CF) Details']][1]/following-sibling::table[1]//tr[not(@type='table-header')]"));

            foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
            {
                //Some logic here
            }
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            driver.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogWriter("WebApplication2.Controllers", ex, "CribController", "Index");
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Why this not working after publishing. how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think we need more context about the error it throws you.

There's a similar question the Selenium GitHub Repository and this was the response https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1125#issuecomment-257258747

You can declare the driver like this:

```
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments(new List<string> { { "start-maximized" } });
IWebDriver driver;
driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
```

Other way that might help is: In the same solution, try to create a Console Application for the Selenium code and executions, calling its constructor from the controller (of the MVC project).

Comment: I am still cant open with this code..